# What is in the output of VeloxChem python based program?

Tags: computational-chemistry

[image]

After running SCF optimization with VeloxChem code the output is a lengthy document at the end of which is this section.

I am wondering what these numbers mean, more specifically in the parentheses?

Comment: I would guess they are the coefficients with largest magnitude for the MOs expressed in the AO basis. But without digging through the manual I can't be sure.

Comment: There should be documentation shipped with the program, either physical copy, or/and via their web site.  Is it https://veloxchem.org/docs/intro.html to point e.g. to literature references (https://veloxchem.org/docs/refs.html)?  Does this workshop (https://enccs.github.io/veloxchem-workshop/) cover somewhat computations you launched?

Comment: I have read through the manual and various references. Nowhere does it say what that part of the output is.

Comment: For future Reference: Please include citations and references. Any text, that is text, like in the case here, should not be included as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output you can search the [source code](https://gitlab.com/veloxchem/veloxchem), which leads to molecularorbitals.py, function `_MolecularOrbitals_print_coefficients`:

```
 """   
 Prints molecular orbital coefficients to output stream.

    :param eigval:
        The eigenvalue (orbital energy).
    :param focc:
        The occupation number of the orbital.
    :param iorb:
        The index (0-based) of the orbital.
    :param coeffs:
        The AO coefficients of the orbital.
    :param ao_map:
        The string representation map of basis functions.
    :param thresh:
        The threshold for priting AO coefficients.
    :param ostream:
        The output stream.
    """


  ostream.print_blank()

    valstr = "Molecular Orbital No.{:4d}:".format(iorb + 1)
    ostream.print_header(valstr.ljust(92))
    valstr = 26 * "-"
    ostream.print_header(valstr.ljust(92))

    valstr = "Occupation: {:.3f} Energy: {:10.5f} a.u.".format(focc, eigval)
    ostream.print_header(valstr.ljust(92))

    tuplist = []

    for i in range(coeffs.shape[0]):

        if math.fabs(coeffs[i]) > thresh:
            atomidx = int(ao_map[i].split()[0])
            anglmom = to_angular_momentum(ao_map[i][-3].upper())
            valstr = "(" + ao_map[i] + ": {:8.2f}".format(coeffs[i]) + ") "
            tuplist.append((atomidx, anglmom, valstr))
```

So the stuff in parentheses is a string representation map of a basis function (`param ao_map`) followed by the corresponding AO coefficient of the orbital (`param coeffs`).

Comment: It's always a good sign when you have to turn to the source code to understand what the software is trying to say…

Comment: @Martin-マーチン could be worse :) The code contains some annotations, at least, and is open source. But you need to read closely, because it's like Ian Bush says: "if math.fabs(coeffs[i]) > thresh:"

Comment: Yes, try things like that with Gaussian. I think there's not a single comment in the source code. Any other choice than what they have done would also have been silly. Once you use real life molecules with real life basis sets, you get a whole bunch of naught zeros. I've also ad a brief look at the docs and found it surprisingly hard to find the source code repo. Anyway, in my next hacking session, I might give this a go.